# I2C Communication to the Matlab from Sensor board(8051 µC)

Tags: i2c, matlab, 8051

I like to connect my board to Matlab through I2C communication(I2C-USB cable).
Is there any library or example scripts in matlab to do it?
What are the procedure to do it.

for example, I connected the device with uart with this code

```
properties (SetAccess = protected)
        sp
        baudRate
        dataBits
        stopBits
        parity
        flowControl
        terminator
        timeout
        port
        waitTime

    end

    methods

        function obj = Dev(comPortName)
            %% Dev constructor for initializing device object properties

            % INPUT PARAMETER
            % * comPortName     - name of the com port (e.g. "COM1")

            % OUTPUT PARAMETER
            % * obj             - initialized device object

            obj.sp          = serial(comPortName);
            obj.baudRate    = 115200;
            obj.dataBits    = 8;
            obj.stopBits    = 1;
            obj.parity      = 'none';
            obj.flowControl = 'none';
            obj.terminator  = 'LF';
            obj.timeout     = 2.5;
            obj.waitTime = 1;

            set(obj.sp, 'BaudRate', obj.baudRate);
            set(obj.sp, 'DataBits', obj.dataBits);
            set(obj.sp, 'StopBits',obj.stopBits);
            set(obj.sp, 'FlowControl',obj.flowControl);
            set(obj.sp, 'Parity',obj.parity);
            set(obj.sp, 'Terminator',obj.terminator);
            set(obj.sp, 'Timeout',obj.timeout);
            %set(obj.sp, 'waitTime',obj.waitTime);

            obj.port = comPortName;
        end
```

similarly, is there a possibility to connect through i2c communication?

Response greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

No Matlab does not have this capability. Special hardware is required.

Here is an [app note where an I2C temperature sensor is read from Matlab](https://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/TemperatureSensor_ADM1034.pdf).
The "I2C2PC" is Serial-> I2C Master. You can control it from matlab.
This is only suitable if your devices are **I2C slave**.

If your device is I2C master, then what you should google for is an "I2C Uart"